# How to delete silence wave in *.wav with c#?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, wav

I am using Microsoft Speech SDK v11 and it works,
but I have some problem with wav,
it always have some white space in wav which the code create,
can I delete those space with c#?

Comment: Take a look at https://naudio.codeplex.com/ It may help.

Comment: I'll try it ,thx a lot!!

Comment: I still have no idea how to solve that...

Comment: Its documentation guides you: https://naudio.codeplex.com/documentation. For example you can see "Trim a WAV File" section here: http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/09/trimming-wav-file-using-naudio.html